# solving a function where [x mod y represents the remainder after division of x by y]

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I would like help solving this practice question.

```
For a function f(x, y) defined below, what is the value of f(775, 527)? Here, x mod y represents the remainder after division of x by y.

f(x, y): if y = 0 then return x else return f(y, x mod y)
```

So it's saying x mod y represents 248?

Using the function definition, y does not equal 0 so that means I need to return f(y, x mod y).

775 mod 527 = 248

775 / 527 = 1 r248

f(527, 775 mod 527) -> f(527, 248) -> 527 mod 248 = 31

I was able to figure out the correct answer 31, however I don't see where it tells me 527, 248 should be solved as x mod y.

Comment: This function is equivalent to $\gcd{(x,y)}$. It performs the Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: This is hard to follow.  At no point is anyone claiming that " x mod y represents $248$".  What would that even mean?

Comment: @Lulu It would mean 248 is congruent to x mod y. @ peter thanks. Could someone explain it?

Comment: Explain what?  Obviously $775 \pmod {527}=248$, there's no mystery there is there?  the function $f(x,y)$ is just $\gcd(x,y)$ except for degenerate cases.  And $\gcd(775,527)=31$.  But your post doesn't even refer to gcd...so I'm just not sure what you are asking.

Comment: What I'm saying is this. The function definition says `return x else return f(y, x mod y)`.  How did you know that `f(y, x mod y)` is the same as `gcd(x,y)` And how do you know that `gcd(x,y)` means the same as `x (mod y)`? Like how did we get from `f(527, 248)` to `527 mod 248`?

Comment: Cf. [Euclidean algorithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EuclideanAlgorithm.html)

Comment: thank you guys.